# Multiple joins with conditions

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to join multiple tables but not exclude the results if a value is matched in either one. This is because a user can be either a musician or a band.

My Tables:

```
Users
------
id, name, location, type (musician or band)

Bands:
id, user_id, experience

Musicians:
id, user_id, experience, commitment
```

My query should return all users (bands or musicians) from a specific location, where experience level equals 'beginner'.

```
// get users
$query = User::select(['id','name','location','type']);

// get bands with experience beginner
$filteredBands = Band::select('user_id', 'id')->where('experience', 'beginner');

// join bands with users
$query->joinSub($filteredBands, 'filtered_bands', function($join) use($data) {
   $join->on('users.id', '=', 'filtered_bands.user_id');
});

// Load the band so I get the nice model structure from laravel
$query->with('band');

// Do the same for Musicians
$filteredMusicians = Musician::select('user_id', 'id')->where('experience', 'beginner');
$query->joinSub($filteredMusicians, 'filtered_musicians', function($join) use($data) {
   $join->on('users.id', '=', 'filtered_musicians.user_id');
});
$query->with('musician');

var_dump($query->get());
```

My problem is that it only gets the users where both the joins are made, where I would like one or the other. IS there a concept of orJoin or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this query that returns the **User** with *Band* or *Musician* record (one has value the other is null).

```
User::where('location','Aus')->with(['band' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('*')->where('experience','beginner');
    }])->with(['musician' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('*')->where('experience','beginner');
    }])->get;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue is that I’m actually doing a query on the user too, and no user result should be returned if band or musician is null. For the user I’m doing $query->where(“location”, “Aus”)

Comment: @BenSouthall I added a `where` now it only fetch users from _Aus_.

Comment: Thanks for that. It still wont quite work as I need it to return only rows in Aus with experience beginner. But your solution will still return Users in aus even if the experience doesn't match 'beginner'. I realised it can't be done by using "with()" it must be a Join. I rewrote my code to use a Join and a UNION. Thanks for your help.